# Single Table Crosscheck Multiple Columns For Duplicate

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table which I would like to check duplicates on across columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `phone_one` varchar(10),
  `phone_two` varchar(10),
  `phone_three` varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES
  ('1', '123456716', '1233345666', ''),
  ('2', '', '', ''),
  ('3', '3902930923', '', '1233345666'),
  ('4', '1233345666', '3902930923', '3902930923'),
  ('5', '1233345667', '3902930924', '3902930924');
```

Which I can check values which are explicitly set and duplicated between the columns as follows:

```
SELECT c.id, d.id AS duplicate 
FROM contacts c 
INNER JOIN contacts d on
    IFNULL(NULLIF(c.phone_one,''), 'NO MATCH') IN (d.phone_one, d.phone_two, d.phone_three)
    OR IFNULL(NULLIF(c.phone_two,''), 'NO MATCH') IN (d.phone_one, d.phone_two, d.phone_three)
    OR IFNULL(NULLIF(c.phone_three,''), 'NO MATCH') IN (d.phone_one, d.phone_two, d.phone_three)
WHERE c.id != d.id
ORDER BY c.id, d.id
```

This example is a subset of a problem I am currently facing. This works for a relatively small number of columns, but gets slow very quickly as the algorithm for this kind of duplicate check has to check the set of each column exponentially (at least, I think my big-O notation check has this as `O(N^2)`).

I am curious to know if there is a more clever solution to this problem. Essentially, does MySQL have a native way of doing this kind of cross-check without needing to append statements to the `IN` clauses?

Comment: Normalize your scheme. AS a palliative unpivot the data in the query using UNION ALL.

Comment: Can you clarify how to do a pivot similar to this?

Comment: Actually, that worked well: I will post an answer here: thanks @Akina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment of Akina, the more efficient way is to run two subqueries to effectively pivot-table by way of `UNION ALL` to perform the cross check.

Essentially, build two identical lists of phone numbers, then join them on the phone number being at least once repeated. Then check that the ID does not match.

Query would look like this:

```
SELECT p1.id as id,
       p2.id as dupid,
       FROM (
           SELECT id, phone_one as phone
           FROM contacts
           UNION ALL
           SELECT id, phone_two as phone
           FROM contacts
           UNION ALL
           SELECT id, phone_three as phone
           FROM contacts
       ) as p1
       INNER JOIN (
           SELECT id, phone_one as phone
           FROM contacts
           UNION ALL
           SELECT id, phone_two as phone
           FROM contacts
           UNION ALL
           SELECT id, phone_three as phone
           FROM contacts
        ) as p2 ON p1.phone = p2.phone
        WHERE p1.id != p2.id
            AND p1.phone != ''
            AND p2.phone != ''
            AND p1.phone is not null
            AND p2.phone is not null;
```

This is appears to be faster due to the fact that the check calculation is only run once at the very end rather than iteratively over the set. As well, it lightens up the null and blank checks to one only one time as well.